# javascript validation in Google gadget

Tags: javascript, html, xml, google-gadget

I am trying to validate a text input to allow only numeric values inside of it and the "." character for a Google gadget that will be inserted in a Google site. The code as HTML and JavaScript on my desktop and laptop works perfectly but when i embed the code inside the XML gadget file and create a gadget from the URL where it is hosted in Google code it does not work on both pc and smart phone, or on anything in fact. the code is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Module>
<ModulePrefs title="On Line Payroll Calculator" /> 
<Content type="html">
<![CDATA[ 
 <style>
  input{
  text-align: right;
  }
 </style>
 <table  id= "mytable" width="50%">
  <tr id = "row1"><!-- Row 1 -->
   <td><label>Basic Salary</label></td><!-- Col 1 -->
   <td><input / type="text" name="salary" onKeyPress="validate(event)"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
  function validate(evt) {
   var theEvent = evt || window.event;
   var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
   key = String.fromCharCode( key );
   var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
   if( !regex.test(key) ) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
   if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
   }
  }
</SCRIPT>
]]>
</Content> 
</Module>
```

question : how to do such validation inside a google site or a google gadget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a input with the type set to number. This will automatically validate itself, without the need for any JS.

```
 <td><input type="number" name="salary"></td>
```

Here's a JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8apDY/

**Here's the pure Javascript solution: http://jsfiddle.net/8apDY/20/**

Comment: unfortunately it did not work, i guess what you are proposion @Xanco works only with HTML5

Comment: me too i am still trying... i guess that it is a question of Google gadgets and sandboxing some javascript features...please update me if you could find something... thank you for your concern

Comment: <td><input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 31 && event.charCode <= 57'></input></td>   this is what i could implement till now @Xanco but the drawback is to lose the tab and the return

Comment: I've done it! I've updated the JsFiddle. I hope that's what you're looking for. Here's the new link http://jsfiddle.net/8apDY/4/

Comment: weird!!! the moment i write in the box it erases everything. i have set     y = document.getElementsByName("salary"); instead of     y = document.getElementsByName("salary")[0]; i can't get why you are doing that?

Comment: I have to add the [0] on the end because they may be more than one element with the name "salary". By adding [0] we're choosing the first element with the name "salary", if we had [1] instead, we'd be choosing the second, and so on ... If we don't do this, it won't work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48890/discussion-between-xanco-and-toufikovich)

Comment: that is great! thank you @Xanco the jsfiddle above is the right way